# Magento 2 how to create a store, store view and root category programatically?

Tags: magento2, multistore, store-view

I was doing a research on how to create this 3 elements, I already have 1 website, but I will have a form that will fill the information of store and store view.

I found this question
https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Magento-2-How-to-create-website-Store-Store-view-Root-Category/td-p/87236 but I have no idea where to put that code.

For example this code for creating an store:

```
private function createOrUpdateGroup($groupId, $websiteId, $storeName, $storeCode)
    {
        $group = $this->groupFactory->create();
        if($groupId)
            $group->load($groupId);

        $group->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
        $group->setName($storeName);
        $group->setCode($storeCode);
        $group->save();

        return $group;
    }
```

Am I supposed to add this private method in the controller where I'm going to submit the form?

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

You can use data patches for these changes.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/data-patches.html